# Format argument for uniform convergence

Tags: analysis

Hi guys so I have this question about uniform convergence that I solved but I wanted to get to see of how rigorous is my argument and there could be done any improvements.

$Let f_n(x) = nx / (1 + nx) for x >=0$

a)Find $f(x) = $ lim $f_n(x)$

b)Show that if t > 0, the convergence is uniform on $[t, \infty]$ 
c) Show that the convergence is not uniform on $[0,\infty]$

Here is my solution

a)first of all we get the point wise limit to be
  $f_n(x) = {0 for x = 0 and 1 otherwise $

b)it will uniformly converge since we have 
$|nx / (1 + nx) - 1| = nx/(1 + nx) <= 1 / (1 + nt)$
so we choose $N = -1 + (1/t*\epsilon)$ so for $n > N$ $1/n < 1/N$

So we get the following :
$nx/(1 + nx) <= 1 / (1 + nt) < (1 + -1 + t * (1/t*\epsilon)) = \epsilon$

And we are done.

c)I argued by continuity so f(t) = {0 if t = 0 and 1 if t = 1} so we get that f(t) isn't continuos at t = 1 so is not uniformly continuos since $f_n$ is continuos but I would like someone to show me the way of doing it by contradiction I am having trouble putting it in words if someone could just show it rigorous way doing the contradiction that would be neat.

Comment: Another way to do c): what is $f_n(1/n)$? (And, what do you mean by "doing it by contradiction"?)

Comment: oh yes it will be always bigger than 1/2 so we choose episolon to be 1/2 and we can never get <= 1/2 and we therefore get a contradiction !

Comment: No need for contradiction. The definition of uniform convergence is not satisfied. The function is therefore not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: what do you think for my argument for b is it rigorous enough ? yes thats what I mean contradiction to the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: It seems a bit off, but mostly right. You could argue: for $x\ge t$,  $|f_n (x) -1|=|1/(1+nx)|\le 1/(nt)$. Now, given $\epsilon>0$, let $N$ be an integer with $Nt>1/\epsilon$. Then it follows that for any $x\ge t$ and any $n>N$ that $|  f_n(x)-1|<\epsilon$.